# Adding multiple rows in an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that allows the user to supply a number and that many rows are appended to the existing table:

```
$('#add-row').click(function() {
    if($('#insert-rows-amnt').val() < 1) {
        alert('Please enter number of rows to insert');
    } else {
        for(i = 1; i <= $('#insert-rows-amnt').val(); i++) {
            $('table tr:last').clone(true).appendTo("tbody");
        }
    }
});
```

Where `#insert-rows-amnt` is an input field and in this case contains the number `5000`.

This currently takes 48 seconds on my machine to add 5,000 additional rows - is there a quicker way of doing this?

I'm not against putting a loading message somewhere if there isn't a way to significantly increase the speed. I'm just curious if this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
  var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
  var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

  if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
    alert('Please enter number of rows to insert');
  } else {

    $tbody = $('table tbody');
    $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');

    additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows + 1).join($row[0].outerHTML);

    $tbody.append(additionalRows);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" />
<button id="add-row" type="button">Add Rows</button>
```

Firstly, don't trust user input, verify you actually have a number, try to parse it and be explicit. Always use the radix, `parseInt()` can try to be too clever for its own good. The result could be NaN or a number, so check for these:

```
var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);

if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
```

If you're using `JQuery`, cache found objects, finding them isn't free, a search is done every time you pass a string selector, so if you've already found it, use it. This ins't going to set the world on fire, but it's a good habit to get into.

Onto the meat of the method, there are two methods for inserting HTML quickly. HTML updates are like Excel Worksheet updates, no small amount of processing goes on when you change the dom. Most of the time this is negligible, but if you're inserting a huge amount of html it's something to be aware of.

- You could create a document fragment and append nodes to it. This gives the benefit of working with objects rather than strings so is less error prone. The essence of it is you create the fragment in memory and insert it once.
- You can create the html as a string and insert it, it's a single dom update, but more error prone as you're string building. This case is simple enough for it to be a good option though.

```
new Array(numNewRows + 1).join($row[0].outerHTML);
```

This replicates a string x number of times. It works by initialising an array of x dimensions and then joining it using a given string as the text between the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Storing $('#insert-rows-amt').val() in a variable should make it faster. Also, you could generate an HTML string in the loop and then append that HTML to the tbody at the end.

```
$('#add-row').click(function() {
var numRows = $('#insert-rows-amnt').val(); 
if(numRows < 1) {
    alert('Please enter number of rows to insert');
} else {
    var htmlString = ''; 
    var clonedRow = $('table tr:last')[0].outerHTML; 
    for(var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        htmlString += clonedRow; 
    }
    htmlString.appendTo("tbody"); 
}
});
```

Comment: Tried saving the number to variable instead but it made no difference unfortunately, I can't create a HTML string either because the table layout is dynamic and may change so I don't know what the html will be at the time the user presses the button

Comment: Can you do something like var clonedRow = $('table tr:last').clone(true);

Comment: And then in your loop do a htmlString += clonedRow

Comment: Edited the answer with the code above.

Comment: would `clonedRow` be implicitly cast to a string though in order to append it to `htmlString`? Or can you apply some sort of `.toString()` method in there?

Comment: Ah. Good point. You could use .html(); (edited above)

Comment: Doesn't `html()` only get the *inner* html?

Comment: Sorry haven't been able to test my code. You could try $('table tr:last')[0].outerHTML;